# Why "Free" is monad if F is functor in Free[F[_], A]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, free-monad

From my understanding, if Foo is monad, so it can be proved to be functor as well. However, I dont understand why in the free monad, if F is functor, Free in  Free[F[_], A] is a monad, so we can use monadic operation to compose codes.

The question is raised when I am reading this blog http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/04/14/free-monads-are-simple.html

In the scalaz, Coyoneda is using type class to present Functor.

```
type Functor = Coyoneda[Action, A]
```

so if Coyoneda implementation is provided, Free[Functor, A] is monad.

Here is code I wrote for the simple code. It is working and pretty cool, so we separate execution and interpretor, but why Free is become a monad for "free"

```
//data type 
sealed trait Action[A]
case class IntOption(number: Int) extends Action[Int]

//implements functor, AKA interpretor
type ScriptImpl[A] = Coyoneda[Action, A]    

object Interpreter extends (Action ~> Option) {
  override def apply[A](a: Action[A]): Option[A] = {
    a match {
      case IntOption(t) => Option(t)
    }
  }
}

//lift to free monad
def toFree[A](a: Action[A]): Free[ScriptImpl, A] = Free.liftFC[Action, A](a)

val result: Free[ScriptImpl, Int] = for {
  a <- toFree(IntOption(1))
  b <- toFree(IntOption(2))
  c <- toFree(IntOption(3))
} yield {
    a + b + c
  }

println(Free.runFC(result)(Interpreter))
```

Comment: Do you know how to prove that *something* is a monad? You find the two natural transformations associated with it and prove they work in accordance to monad laws.

Comment: I'd suggest not using the name `Functor` for your coyoneda'd `Action`—it will hide `scalaz.Functor` and is potentially confusing.

Comment: `Free[ScriptImpl, ?]` is a monad because it's constructed to be one - `Free` has implementations of `map` and `flatMap` (which obey the monad laws), just as, say, `List` is a  monad.